# R: Deleting elements from a vector based on element length

Tags: string, r, vector, subset

How can I delete elements from a vector of strings depending on the number of characters or length of the strings?

```
df <- c("asdf","fweafewwf","af","","","aewfawefwef","awefWEfawefawef")
> df
[1] "asdf"            "fweafewwf"       "af"              ""                ""                "aewfawefwef"     "awefWEfawefawef"
```

For example, I may want to delete all elements of `df` with a length smaller than 5, so the output would be:

```
> df
[1]"fweafewwf"        "aewfawefwef"     "awefWEfawefawef"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `nchar`:

```
> df[nchar(df) > 5]
[1] "fweafewwf"       "aewfawefwef"     "awefWEfawefawef"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `nchar` works weird with NA's:

```
nchar(NA)
## [1] 2
```

I recommend to use `stri_length` function from `stringi` package

```
require(stringi)
df[stri_length(df)>5]
```