# Using the "nchar" function on a data.frame in R?

Tags: r

This is a follow up question to another question that I found through google:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142482/r-deleting-elements-from-a-vector-based-on-element-length)

I have a data frame with many different names (all of them character strings) and I want to remove the observations that have 5 or less characters in them.

From the previous question that I've linked to, using the "nchar" function on a vector value works well:

```
df <- c("asdf","fweafewwf","af","","","aewfawefwef","awefWEfawefawef")
> df[nchar(df) > 5]
[1] "fweafewwf"       "aewfawefwef"     "awefWEfawefawef"
```

However, if I try to do the same on a data frame, nothing happens:

```
df <- data.frame(c("asdf","fweafewwf","af","","","aewfawefwef","awefWEfawefawef"))
> df[nchar(df) > 5]
[1] "asdf"            "fweafewwf"       "af"              ""                ""                "aewfawefwef"     "awefWEfawefawef"
```

Is it possible to get the same output using the simple "nchar" function with a data frame? Or would you recommend something else?

Comment: `nchar` works on a single vector.  A data frame is a list of vectors.  You can subset the column then run it, but you'll need to coerce the column to character first since it's currently a factor. `nchar(as.character(df[[1]])` And it's best to assign column names to your data frame

Comment: Great comment Rich

Comment: @RichScriven Thanks for your help, you're right the class was a factor. I've changed the class and given the data frame a column name now. I then use     df <- df$Names[nchar(df$Names) > 5]

and once it's done I convert it back to a data frame, and that seems to do the trick.